# ef one-to-one referential integrity constraint violation

Tags: entity-framework-6, one-to-one

There are three entities:

```
class A 
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Z { get; set; }
   public virtual B Bc { get; set; }
   public virtual C Cc { get; set; }
}

class B
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string X { get; set; }
   public virtual A Ac { get; set; } 
}

class C
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Y { get; set; }
   public virtual A Ac { get; set; } 
}
```

I would like the 'A' class to be in a one-to-one connection with the 'B' class or 'C' class but only with one of them.
The one-to-one connections are ready among tables in the database.

I tried to use fluent mapping to establish their relationship but I always got error when I wanted to insert A:

> A referential integrity constraint violation occurred: The property value(s) of 'A.ID' on one end of a relationship do not match the property value(s) of 'B.ID' on the other end.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<A>()
  .HasOptional(x => x.B)
  .WithRequired();

modelBuilder.Entity<A>()
  .HasOptional(x => x.C)
  .WithRequired();
```

OR

```
modelBuilder.Entity<B>() 
  .HasRequired(t => t.A) 
  .WithOptional(t => t.B);

modelBuilder.Entity<C>() 
  .HasRequired(t => t.A) 
  .WithOptional(t => t.C);
```

What is the solution, please?

**EDIT:**

1. I save A.
2. B.ID = A.ID
3. I save B.